# Output parametric bean property with struts tags

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl, struts-tags

I got a bean `beanName` and a variable `paramName` that holds the name of the property to be used so that:

```
<s:textfield name="%{'beanName.' + paramName}"/>
```

outputs (given `paramName == "year"` and `beanName.getYear() == 1976`):

```
<input type="text" name="beanName.year" value="1976" >
```

How am I supposed to use `<s:property>` to output the same property value?

I'd suppose that:

```
<s:push value="beanName">
   <s:property value="%{paramName}"/>
</s:push>
```

would do that, but it just writes `paramName` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to evaluate `paramName` first before using it to get value from the bean.

Use square brackets for that:

```
<s:property value="beanName[paramName]" />
```

OGNL firstly gets value of `paramName` and then gets value from `beanName` with this resolved variable.